# Make it easier to refer to an answer with the poster's name

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, reference

If, in a question, answer or comment, I want to refer to someone's answer, I usually also want to mention their username, e.g. `@SomePerson's [answer](https://link.goes.here)`. That means I have to:

1. Scroll up or down to the answer.
2. Right-click "share" to copy the link.
3. Memorize the exact spelling of the user's name (sometimes difficult for non-Latin or long names)
4. Type in something like the string above.

It would be much nicer if this was made easier.

My specific idea: Some type-ahead suggestion could offer to do some of the above for me. There's already a username suggestion for other people in the same comment thread, for example - so perhaps that could be expanded.

**edit:** Do you have additional suggestions for handling this inconvenience? Is my mechanism not a good idea? Let's brainstorm.

Comment: Might be even better if a link to an answer is automatically formatted like question ones. But if it's an answer it also refers to the user, so it formats like `<site>/a/123456` -> `[SomePerson's answer](<site>/a/123456)` or whatever uniform way would be acceptable.

Comment: Instead of a suggestion/autocomplete when typing maybe an extra "Copy link" link with the proposed markup could be added to the _Share_ left-click modal. Possibly better as a userscript because of the relatively infrequent use case and limited SE developer time. A problem with either implementation would be that usernames change, which would be an argument against mentioning the username at all (I usually say `in [one of the other answers](link)`).

Comment: @Marijn: That's possible, but then people would need to distinguish 'share' from 'copy link', which is not trivial; plus you would still need to scroll there and back.

Comment: You can: 1) Copy the Share link, 2) Paste the share link. 3) Copy the user display name, 4) Paste the user display name. No need to memorize anything.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron: So I would need to scroll _twice_? That's nuts. No way.

Comment: @Marijn VLAZ's suggestion takes care of the username change issue; question links that are automatically formatted always use the current question title.

Comment: @VLAZ: Could you make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron or, if you use a clipboard manager, copy both, then paste one, get the second one from the clipboard manager. Not sure how many people use clipboard managers, though. Probably more than before Windows had a built-in one (Win+V), however, I'd expect it's not too wide spread.

Comment: A way to avoid the scrolling is to open the referenced answer in a new browser tab (presuming desktop), but yes, the system ought to support this very common operation (if nothing else to make sure the reference breaks when the user name changes (by the user or when the account is deleted)). Though it could be argued why this cross referencing is necessary in the first place.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: I don't think there's an argument about it often being necessary and useful, e.g.: "X's answer address issue A, while Y's answer addresses issue B, so perhaps you should combine / here is my idea which addresses both".

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum: See a concrete example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490578/1593077).

Comment: \*the reference does not break

Comment: @einpoklum well you can scroll once, and copy the answer link and author name to some other application like Notepad (or Notes on mobile), then form the comment there, and copy the ready-to-post comment. Or even better, use some clipboard manager, like someone else suggested in a comment. :)

Comment: Actually, I always do double links: one for the author, one for the answer...

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar: I could also type everything with one hand behind my back for increased effect :-P

Answer (score 8):

Give it [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/786798) for Stack Exchange to come around. In the meantime, I [created a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/9393/78873) that does exactly what you ask for and more:

1. Post lookup presented as a sortable and filterable reference table.
2. SE API integration for fetching posts from other pages / network sites.
3. Auto-generation of proper post references (with profile and post links).
4. "Scroll to post" feature when clicking on the post type in the table.

[image: answer referencing workflow]

Answer (score 4):

It might be even better if a link to an answer is automatically formatted like question ones.

For example, the short link to this question is:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376020
```

Which when used in a post automatically converts to a link and uses the title of the question as the anchor text:

[Make it easier to refer to an answer with the poster's name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376020)

In a similar fashion a link to an answer can be automatically formatted in a uniform way to .

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376033
```

could become

```
[VLAZ's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376033)
```

or whatever most acceptable way would be.

This also means that links would always use the current username.

Comment: The replacement text might need to be contextual to where you paste the link. ... and - even with your suggestion, there's no reason not to offer some auto-complete to this effect when typing comments or answers.

Comment: @einpoklum In this case, I'm happy to leave the implementation details open. Yes, it might make sense to have it contextual, for example pasting a link to an answer to the same question would just say "Somebody's answer" while pasting a link to another question might format it as "Somebody's answer to <title of question>". Ultimately, I don't want to impose a rigid solution here, though, other than the general mechanism.